# Speed up the xml file generation from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geopandas

This is my first post so please bear with me. I have searched in the forums and found parts to my issue, hence the question.
I am looking way to expedite the XML file generation process from a pandas dataframe using python.
The geodataframe has around 3 million records representing segments of the cities roadway. Majority of the records are unique.
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aaf4f.png) 
Given that it is heavy file, I want to vectorize the process as much as I can, however I can get my head around how to do generate XML file. My present code takes 15min for each 10,000 record track.
The present code is as follows

```py
def read_pickle(rd_ntwrk, rd_nodes):
    """
    Here we are reading the roadnetwork geo-dataframe.
    Iterating over each row, we are trying to create road_network.xml file.
    The road_network.xml file has two major sections with root= "networks" governed by DTD file
    1. nodes: this contains details about all road nodes. Nodes has subchild equal to "node", with each node distinctly identified using attributes X,Y and Node_ID
    attrib = {id:node_id, X:x, Y:y}
    2. links: this contains details about the network links (road segments). Links has subchild "link", with each link distinctly identified using attributes like id, from, to, length, freespeed, capacity, permlanes, oneway, modes 
attrib = {id:link_id, from:from_node_id, to:to_node_id, length:length_m, freespeed:free_speed,
              capacity:capacity, permlanes:lanes, oneway:oneWay, modes:"modes"}
    """
    # shapes=pd.read_csv(data_dir.joinpath('shapes.csv'))
    colmns = ["toIntersectionId", "fromIntersectionId", "free_speed", "lanes", "bike_access", "drive_access", "walk_access",
              "model_link_id", "oneWay", "rail_only", "transit_access","bus_only",
              "length_m", "capacity_per_lane","transit"]

    road = rd_ntwrk.copy()[colmns]  # keep only filter columns

    road["capacity"] = (road["capacity_per_lane"].astype(float)) * (road["lanes"].astype(float))
    colmns.remove("oneWay")
    colmns.remove("capacity_per_lane")
    colmns.remove("transit_access")
    # colmns.remove("transit")
    colmns.append("capacity")

    added_nodes = []
    added_links = []
    root = ET.Element("network")
    nodes = ET.SubElement(root, "nodes")
    links = ET.SubElement(root, "links",
                          {"capperiod": "01:00:00", "effectivecellsize": "7.5", "effectivelanewidth": "3.75"})
    i = 0
    for index, row in road.iterrows():  # iterate over the rows of the road network
        # dataframe
        # attrib = {id:link_id, from:from_node_id, to:to_node_id, length:length_m, freespeed:free_speed,
        #               capacity:capacity, permlanes:lanes, oneway:oneWay, modes:"modes"}
        # while i<=10:
        link_dict = {}
        modes = []
        for col in colmns:
            val = row.loc[col]
            if col == "toIntersectionId":
                toIntersection = rd_nodes.loc[rd_nodes["shst_node_id"] == val, "model_node_id"].values[0]
                latitude = rd_nodes.loc[rd_nodes["shst_node_id"] == val, "Y"].values[0]
                longitude = rd_nodes.loc[rd_nodes["shst_node_id"] == val, "X"].values[0]
                if toIntersection not in added_nodes:
                    ET.SubElement(nodes, "node", {"id": str(toIntersection), "x": str(longitude), "y": str(latitude)})
                    added_nodes.append(toIntersection)
                    link_dict["from"] = str(toIntersection)
            elif col == "fromIntersectionId":
                fromIntersection = rd_nodes.loc[rd_nodes["shst_node_id"] == val, "model_node_id"].values[0]
                latitude = rd_nodes.loc[rd_nodes["shst_node_id"] == val, "Y"].values[0]
                longitude = rd_nodes.loc[rd_nodes["shst_node_id"] == val, "X"].values[0]
                if fromIntersection not in added_nodes:
                    ET.SubElement(nodes, "node", {"id": str(fromIntersection), "x": str(longitude), "y": str(latitude)})
                    added_nodes.append(fromIntersection)
                    link_dict["to"] = str(fromIntersection)
            elif col == "free_speed":
                val = 0 if (np.isnan(row.loc[col]) or (row.loc[col]) == 0) else float(row.loc[col])
                link_dict["freespeed"] = str(round(val,2))
            elif col == "lanes":
                val = 0 if (row.loc[col]) == 0 else float(row.loc[col])
                link_dict["permlanes"] = str(round(val,1))
            elif col == "bike_access":
                val = "bike" if row.loc[col] == 1 else ""
                modes.append(val)
            elif col == "drive_access":
                val = "car" if row.loc[col] == 1 else ""
                modes.append(val)
            elif col == "walk_access":
                val = "walk" if row.loc[col] == 1 else ""
                modes.append(val)
            elif col == "model_link_id":
                val = 0 if (np.isnan(row.loc[col]) or (row.loc[col]) == 0) else float(row.loc[col])
                link_dict["id"] = str(round(val))
            elif col == "rail_only":
                val = "rail" if row.loc[col] == 1 else ""
                modes.append(val)
            elif col == "bus_only":
                val = "bus" if row.loc[col] == 1 else ""
                modes.append(val)
            elif col == "length_m":
                val = 0 if (np.isnan(row.loc[col]) or (row.loc[col]) == 0) else round(float(row.loc[col]),2)
                link_dict["length"] = str(val)
            elif col == "capacity":
                val = 0 if (row.loc[col]) == 0 else round(float(row.loc[col]),2)
                link_dict["capacity"] = str(val)
            else:
                link_dict["oneway"] = str(1.0)
                modes = list(filter(None, modes))
                if len(modes)>1:
                    link_dict["modes"] = ', '.join(map(str, modes))
                else:
                    link_dict["modes"]=str(modes[0])
        if link_dict["id"] not in added_links:
            added_links.append(link_dict["id"])
            print(link_dict)
            ET.SubElement(links, "link", attrib=link_dict)
    return root
```

The "from" and "to "nodes ID are fetched from the other file which contains the location details for each point geometry.

Sample network and node data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C_wuudENDbJm5d-L04xt7HHhlOLEvCtM?usp=sharing)

Any ideas or direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the question? What have you tried so far? Why it did not work out? Also, please put sample data in the format that can be easily copied, otherwise someone would have to spend their time just rewritting data

Comment: I have edited my original question.